# Aspose size of document increase after inserting an image

Tags: asp.net, .net, aspose

We are using aspose to generate word and pdf report.And the report size is around 1.5 mb without any image embedded in it.
We are using 
    documentBuilder.InsertImage(byte [] byteArray)
for passing a byte array of size 61 kb. but after inserting the image the size of the document becomes 15 mb.
Is there any way to reduce the size of the document
We are using licenced aspose.net version

Answer (score 0):

I tried your scenario with a word file (1.75 MB) and image file (1 MB high resolution) and used DocumentBuilder.InsertImage(byte [] byteArray) method to insert image to word file. The resultant file is around 3.5 MB (generated with Aspose.Words). If I insert the same image using MS Word, the resultant file size is 2.75 MB. So, there is a difference between Aspose.Words and MS Words output. But, in your case the difference is huge.

Causes can be:

```
1: Your code might be adding image multiple times causing file size
to grow.

2: Issue might be specific to your word file or image file.

3: You might be using an old version of Aspose.Words API.
```

I would suggest you to:

```
1: Share your code here to check if it is same as mine.

2: Download and try the latest version of Aspose.Words API as Aspose
team is constantly working on improving the performance and seeing
your results, it seems you might be using an older version.

3: Share your word document and image file on Aspose Support Forums
and Aspose team can further investigate your issue.
```